# please explain cakephp acl parent id and foreign key

Tags: cakephp, acl

I try to understand of acl component but difficult for newbie 
but i try to insert data to table and capture screen and make [arrow](http://uppic.net/full/94fd6a151a6cad89978e3419eac90401)
for to make myself understand and I can' understand foriegn key and parent id 
in aro and aco table and other I need example in the case of many role and many aro and aco
I'm student and use cakephp in final project and trying to compose a sentence 
thank you for try to understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I find a a bit difficult to understand your question I'm trying to help with these links which explain ACL in CakePHP very good:

[Tutorial für ACL controlled app](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application)

[Explanation of the ACL Component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists)

[API-Entry for the ACL Component](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/acl-component)

But just to explain what the two keys "foreign_key" and "parent_id" are for:

**foreign_key**

This is used to link an ARO (Access Request Object) to it's correspondent entry in the database. You could, for example, link a user to it's correspondent ARO and benefit from Cakes associations between them and have all information in one place.

**parent_id**

This is used to build the tree structure of the ACOs (Access Controll Objects). If you provide a parent_id the structure could look like this:

```
Your_Controller (has id 5)
    Your_First_Method (has id 6 and parent_id 5)
    Your_Second_Method (has id 7 and parent_id 5)
```

As you can see, you get a nice hierarchic structure of your ACOs.

I hope this helps you in better understanding CakePHPs ACL.